# Troubleshooting an intermittently slow internet connection on multiple devices

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet-connection

Every now and then, especially over the recent Christmas period, my practical internet speeds will drop **way** below the theoretical maximum...I mean like taking *10 minutes* to download a file that's only 1 or 2 MB in size! Chrome usually times out before then and I have to retry the download, which is incredibly frustrating when all I want is a simple PDF or small media file!

My theoretical max is 50 mbps down/20 mbps up and I get close to those speeds every time I visit a speed test website, so are there any other free tools for troubleshooting an issue like this? It happens across multiple websites and at seemingly-random intervals, so I don't believe that it could be a DNS or server issue, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

I have rung my ISP (Telstra in Australia, who are notorious for this sort of thing) *five times* over the past month and they keep assuring me that there is nothing on their end causing the problem. I've also asked their techs that I've spoken to whether neighbourhood congestion could be the cause, but 3/5 said "No, there's more than enough bandwidth to go around for the current demand". The other two said it's a possibility, but said that my client devices or router were more likely to be the culprit.

The latter makes sense but once again, how would I investigate that possibility further? The former seems unlikely to me since I have a cable TV box, Xbox One, two desktops, a laptop and a smartphone **all** experiencing this issue. I rarely use more than one of them at a time though.

My router is a [Netgear V7610](https://www.telstra.com.au/content/dam/tcom/small-business/broadband/pdf/telstra-gateway-pro-v7610-user-guide.pdf) which is manufactured specifically for Telstra in Australia, and is [notorious for being an absolute hunk of junk in general](https://forums.whirlpool.net.au/thread/360yx173). That link is just one of many describing various issues that people have had with this thing.

As such I'm thinking about getting an [Archer C7](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.tp-link.com/au/service-provider/wireless-routers/archer-c7/&ved=2ahUKEwiQh968luHmAhWRguYKHU5FD64QFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw2NghMu-vZ2DKcvRJV1OnQk) and flashing it with DD-WRT. I've had advice from friends (one of whom is a retired network engineer) that the custom firmware alone could improve things greatly, and even if it doesn't, at least I'll have better logging and troubleshooting capabilities. Any thoughts?

Comment: "So recommendations of a cheap but reliable wireless router" We don't do hardware (or software) recommendations on [su].

Comment: Fair enough @DavidPostill, I will do some more research into this myself. I have already done a few hours worth but didn't come up with much :-(

Comment: I used this speed test before: http://speedtest.att.com/speedtest/ maybe that will give you different results. Especially if you use your provider's speed test, they may be lying, who knows... :-)

Comment: @AlexisWilke "They may be lying..." Yeah I wouldn't put it past them! I've been using Ookla's speed test and the one that Google provides if you just search for "speed test", but I'll give the AT&T one a go as well. Thanks for the tip! :D

Comment: @AlexisWilke same results as usual...so if I can get close to my theoretical max speeds on any test, what potential causes does that rule out?

Comment: What type of DSL is this? Does the web GUI of the Netgear give you log data for the WAN connection? Does it give you signal to noise data anywhere? If it does please post some screen shots of it when it's acting goofy, and when you are hitting your ISP cap in a speed test.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I believe my connection uses VDSL over fibre optic cable, but am finding it difficult to confirm that. My ISP nor [NBN Co.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.nbnco.com.au/&ved=2ahUKEwjxvsGtlOHmAhV84jgGHUJ7Ag0QFjAAegQIAxAD&usg=AOvVaw3G5T9DMHXiNBm9-D9gZ7Gb) seem to like giving out technical info about how any of this actually works. I've also edited the question to address your "check the logs" suggestion. Would very much appreciate your thoughts :-)

Comment: I would recommend openwrt over ddwrt. Both will work, IMHO ddwrt is considerably less stable. Without snr readings it's almost impossible to say who or what devices are at fault.